# What effect does the score have in Kirby: Mass Attack?

Tags: kirby-mass-attack

From what I can tell, score seems to have no effect on the game. The manual makes no mention of it, and also states it does not affect your rating at the end of a level.

Does score have any impact on the game, or has Nintendo just kept it in for the sake of keeping it old-school?

[image]

Comment: Score shows up in a lot of nintendo games as a meaningless number that is tracked anyway. Case in Point: Super Mario World.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Yeah I know. I'm assuming the same is true for Kirby, but figured I mine as well ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading through the manual, searching online, and my playtime in the game I can safely say score serves no purpose in Kirby: Mass Attack.

Answer (score 4):

After the end credits when you've beaten the game, it will show many statistics, one of which being your grand total of points (from all stages added up).  I had over 2 million points, apparently.

So it's just a statistic, good for bragging rights I guess, like with most Mario games.  You get several other statistics too after the end credits!